# using hover() on dynamically created elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use jQuery's `hover()` on dynamically created elements. I tried the below but no success. How can I do this? I can not use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` because this page will be embedded inside an iframe.

```
$(document).on('hover', '.dynamic', function(){
    //do
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [hover()](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) is not an event, it is a utility method used to register both [mouseenter](https://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [mouseleave](https://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) event handlers.

> The .hover() method binds handlers for both mouseenter and mouseleave
>   events. You can use it to simply apply behavior to an element during
>   the time the mouse is within the element.

So you can use mouseenter and mouseleave event handlers for the dynamic elements

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.dynamic', function () {
    //do
}).on('mouseleave', '.dynamic', function () {
    //do
});
```

---

If you want to have a single handler for both then

```
$(document).on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.dynamic', function () {
    //do
});
```

Comment: thanks. But `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` will not work when the page is embedded in an iframe?

Comment: @Becky if you see the above quote, the hover method just registers both these handlers... so if hover works, the above code also should work fine

Comment: I've read that mouseenter and mouseleave will not work when the page is embedded in an iframe. thank you Arun. I'll give it a go. :)